# What is the meaning of @(${VAR})?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

Whilst looking at some shell scripts I encountered several instances of if statements comparing some normal variable against another variable which is enclosed in @( ) brackets.

Does @(....) have some special meaning or am I missing something obvious here? Example of if test:

```
if [[ ${VAR} != @(${VAR2}) ]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an extended pattern, borrowed from `ksh`. Originally you would need to enable support for it with `shopt -s extglob`, but it became the default behavior inside `[[ ... ]]` in `bash` 4.1. `@(...)` matches one of the enclosed patterns. By itself, `@(pattern)` and `pattern` would be equivalent, so I would assume that the contents of `$VAR2` contains at least one pipe, so that the expansion is something like `@(foo|bar)`. In that case, the test would succeed if `$VAR1` does *not* match `foo` or `bar`.

Comment: +1; good to know about the change in default behavior in 4.1.

Comment: +1: I didn't even know such expansion existed. Looked `perl` to me!

Comment: Note that the man page for 4.1 seems to imply that only `!(...)` requires `extglob` to be set, but this is fixed again in 4.2.

Answer (score 2):

From the `bash` man page:

> ```
>          @(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one of the given patterns
> ```

So `${VAR2}` is expected to be a list of patterns separated by `|`, and your code tests whether `${VAR}` matches any of them.